# How to call a JavaScript function onchange of a select tag?

Tags: html, select, onchange

Below is my JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkit()
{  
var state=document.frm.getElementById(stateS)
if (state="Please select a state")
    {
    document.frm.Month.disable = true;
    }
else
    {
    document.frm.Month.enable = true;
    }   
}</script>
```

and I call `checkit()` function in it from below `<select>` tag:

```
<td align="left"><g:select name="Month" from="${month.values()}" optionValue="${Month}" onChange=checkit()/></td>
 </tr>
```

I have a select tag for state and until I select any state the month select box should be disabled. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

actually there is a " missing there, it should be

```
onChange="checkit();"
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `onchange` to `onChange="checkit(this);` and then something like the below in `checkit`

```
function checkit(selectObj)
{ 
  var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
  document.frm.Month.disabled = idx == 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not working.in check it function i am checking if state is selected in state select box if not then i want month select box to be disabled.i have changed it to onChange=checkit(this)

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I assumed that the "Please select a state" was the first in the list (index 0). `idx == 0` will result in `true` only when `idx` is 0. What's that `g:` in front of `select`?

Answer (score 1):

by id jquery-1.9.1

```
$('#selectBox').on('change', function() 
{
    value= this.value;
    if(value==0)
      {
        //code
      }
    else if(value==1)
      {
         //code
      }
     ...
     else
      {
         //code
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("select").onchange = function() {myFunction()};`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put its javascript function *before* the input tag is generated.
EG.outside *jourJSframework*(document).ready function or before the <\head> closing tag of your html document.